# not able to make a button visible from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I created an image gallery app.

**My requirment**:When I click on *buttoncut* in a activity(PhotosActivity.java), *buttonpaste* should become visible and it should remain visible when I go back to another activity(ImageGallery.java) so that I can use it for moving pictures to another folder.

**What is happening:** When I click on *buttoncut*(PhotosActivity.java), *buttonpaste* becomes visible but when I go back to any other activity(ImageGallery.java), it disappears.
I tried some code but its not working. How can I fix it ?

PhotosActivity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PhotosActivity.this, ImageGallery.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IS_CORRECT, true);
startActivity(intent);
```

ImageGallery.java

```
Intent startingIntent = getIntent();
boolean isCorrect = startingIntent.getBooleanExtra(PhotosActivity.EXTRA_IS_CORRECT, false);

if(isCorrect) {
    final ImageButton buttonpaste = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonpaste);
    buttonpaste.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: You can use fragment also

Comment: you need to save the state of your button. so that when you come back it's state is reserved. :) you really need to understand activity life cycle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when I go back to any other activity(ImageGallery.java), it disappears

Because you have a different Intent when you "go back". If you want to persist the visibility, you should probably be using `SharedPreferences`.

For example

```
ImageButton buttonpaste = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonpaste);
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs" Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isCorrect = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(PhotosActivity.EXTRA_IS_CORRECT, false);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = prefs.edit();

if(isCorrect || prefs.getBoolean(PhotosActivity.EXTRA_IS_CORRECT,false)) {
    buttonpaste.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    e.putBoolean(PhotosActivity.EXTRA_IS_CORRECT, true);
    e.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main Activity use **startActivityForResult** instead of **startActivity**. This allows you to return a value from the **new Activity** to the **Main Activity**. For example:

In PhotosActivity

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(PhotosActivity.this, ImageGallery.class), 3);
```

Here, number 3 is a number you define that allows you to identify the result later.

```
setResult(RESULT_OK); // or any result you want
```

The result is sent to the MainActivity, and you must override onActivityResult() to get the result.

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == 3) // here you match the number you sent in startActivityForResult
        if (resultcode == RESULT_OK)
             // do something
}
```